# Trying to 'install' a trigger from script editor returns 'You do not have permission to call newTrigger"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So, I've been trying to send an email through MailApp inside an onFormSubmit function. I recently learnt that simple triggers don't have extended access to services such as mail but installable's do.

So off I went to scour the internet for how to make an installable trigger, I don't understand the google documentation for them in the slightest, nor have I found a single helpful video/forum anywhere on them that makes them easy to understand,

therefore I turn to you, you bunch of geniuses.

Through the script editor, I'm calling this manually

```
function CreateFormSubmitTrigger() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger('formDone')
.forSpreadsheet(ss)
.onFormSubmit()
.create()

}
```

every time I run it, it returns "You do not have permission to call newTrigger (line 7, file "Code")"

The function I'm trying to make a trigger for is below, When I had this on current project triggers > spreadsheet > onFormSubmit. It wasn't working either.

```
function formDone(e) {

Utilities.sleep(3000)

var range = e.range;
var ss = range.getSheet();
var row = range.getRowIndex();

var tactics = 
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('id', "A:AQ"+row);

var headers = 
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('id', 'A1:U1');
var templateID = "id"

var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length;

var Timestamp = tactics.values[i][0];
var IDCFREF = tactics.values[i][2];
var raisedby = tactics.values[i][4];
var AccMan = tactics.values[i][6];
var Contrib = tactics.values[i][7];
var Contract = tactics.values[i][8];
var CompName = tactics.values[i][9];
var ValidFrom = tactics.values[i][10];
var ValidTo = tactics.values[i][11];
var Freq = tactics.values[i][12];
var PDetailFreq = tactics.values[i][13];
var BillType = tactics.values[i][14];
var TypeOfRebate = tactics.values[i][15];
var RebateDetails = tactics.values[i][16];
var RTarget = tactics.values[i][17];
var GiveDeets = tactics.values[i][19];
var WhyGiveRebate = tactics.values[i][20];
var documentID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy().getId();

console.log({message: IDCFREF})

if (DriveApp.getFilesByName("Rebate " + IDCFREF + " Request").hasNext()){
    DriveApp.getFilesByName("Rebate " + IDCFREF + " Request").next().setTrashed(true)
    } else {
    }
DriveApp.getFileById(documentID).setName('Rebate ' + IDCFREF + ' Request');

var body1 = DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody();
var header = DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getHeader();

header.replaceText('##IDCF##', IDCFREF)
body1.replaceText('##REF##', IDCFREF)
body1.replaceText('##RAISED##', raisedby)
body1.replaceText('##ACCMAN##', AccMan)
body1.replaceText('##CONTRIB##', Contrib)
body1.replaceText('##SIGNED##', Contract)
body1.replaceText('##NAME##', CompName)
body1.replaceText('##FROM##', ValidFrom)
body1.replaceText('##TO##', ValidTo)
body1.replaceText('##FREQ##', Freq)
body1.replaceText('##BESPOKE##', PDetailFreq)
body1.replaceText('##BILL##', BillType)
body1.replaceText('##TYPE##', TypeOfRebate)
body1.replaceText('##DEETS##', RebateDetails)
body1.replaceText('##TARGET##', RTarget)
body1.replaceText('##FULL##', GiveDeets)
body1.replaceText('##ELAB##', WhyGiveRebate)

Utilities.sleep(5000)

var filemail = DriveApp.getFileById(documentID)

if(DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody().findText("#")) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "email",
  subject: "Rebate Request " + IDCFREF + " - Pending",
  body: "",

  attachments: [filemail]
  })
    } else {

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "email",
  subject: "Rebate Request " + IDCFREF + " - Complete",
  body: "rebates",

  attachments: [filemail]
  });
 }
}
```

Any light on the situation would be met by unparalleled appreciation.

Cheers

Comment: You've disabled automatic scope detection by manually specifying scopes in your manifest file. Either remove all scopes (and thus reenable automatic scope detection) or add the proper scope to your manifest file.

Comment: @tehhowch ahahaha what a friggin legend. I didn't even mention oauth scopes and you knew can you post it as an answer so I can give you the rep you deserve